# Angular2 ControlValueAccessor

Tags: binding, angular, components, controls

i'm trying to understand how ControlValueAccessor work precisely.

I have studied the behavior of it with two different control component:

- The first is suppose to provide a primitive value: a single number.
- The second provide a complex object.

So in short:

```
class FirstControlComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
    // ...
    value:number = 10;
    writeValue(value: number) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    // ...
}

class SecondControlComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
    // ...
    value:any = {};
    writeValue(value: any) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    // ...
}
```

The ControlValueAccessor interface only specify a 'setter': **writeValue**, but no 'getter'.

So when i bind a Control to SecondControlComponent, something like:

```
this.form = this.builder.group({
    controlName: this.builder.control(this.theObject) });
```

and later in the template:

```
<second-component ngControl='controlName'> <second-component>
```

Everything works just fine, because writeValue is called on init with a reference to the existing theObject object, so the control modify the same instance of the object (hope i'm clear)

**BUT:** if i do exactly the same thing with FirstControlComponent, **because** the value is not passed as a reference (cause it's a primitive), and **because** ControlValueAccessor do not provide a 'setter' the value in my control and the value in my host component are NOT kept in sync ...

Does this mean that we HAVE to pass Object and not primitive to custom control implementing the ControlValueAccessor? I Guess no, so i guess i must be misunderstanding something .. :)

I'm using it the right way ?

Any hints are welcome !

Thanks !

Comment: Controls have a property `updateValue()` to set the value.

Comment: And i guess that updateValue() will call writeValue() on the binded control component. 
But what happen if the control component itself change it's value ? How this change is reflected to the control in the form ?

Comment: read [Never again be confused when implementing ControlValueAccessor in Angular forms](https://blog.angularindepth.com/never-again-be-confused-when-implementing-controlvalueaccessor-in-angular-forms-93b9eee9ee83)

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me what you try to do here but `ControlValueAccessor` is an entity that you need to register for your element. Something like that:

```
const CUSTOM_VALUE_ACCESSOR = new Provider(
    NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, {useExisting: forwardRef(() => LabelsValueAccessor), multi: true});

@Directive({
  (...)
  providers: [CUSTOM_VALUE_ACCESSOR]
})
export class LabelsValueAccessor implements ControlValueAccessor {
  (...)
}
```

It will then take part of the value updates (from component and from the template). When you set a value within the component on the input (for example), the `writeValue` method is called in your value accessor. If you want to update the input value from the value accessor, you need to leverage the registered onChange callback by Angular2

See this article (section "NgModel-compatible component") for more details:

- http://restlet.com/blog/2016/02/17/implementing-angular2-forms-beyond-basics-part-2/

Answer (score 0):

In Parent Component I want output of form like this `{someOtherControlName: any, controlName: number}` so output of Child form must be number.also in update form (example) `parentform.patchValue({someOtherControlName: '', controlNmae: 3})` value of formControl must set properly

```
@Component({
selector: 'parent',
template: `
    <div [formGroup]="form">
    <second-component [formControl]='form.controlName'> <second-component>
    <div formControlName="someOtherControlName"></div>
 export class ParentComponent {
    parentForm = new FormGroup({
       controlName: new FormControl(),  <<<<<======important
       someOtherControlName: new FormControl()
    })
}
```

In ControlValueAccessor:

```
@Component({
selector: 'counter',
template: `
    <div class="number-input" [formGroup]="form">
        <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" formControlName="counter" />
</div>
`,
styleUrls: ['counter.component.scss'],
providers: [
    {
        provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
        useExisting: CounterComponent,
        multi: true,
    },
],
})
 export class CounterComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, OnDestroy, OnInit {
   form = new FormGroup({
    counter: new FormControl(0, Validators.required),
   })

    private onChange: (value: any) => void = value => {}
    private onTouched: () => void = () => {}
    myValue: number
    private onDestroy$: Subject<void> = new Subject()
    ngOnInit() {
    this.form.valueChanges
        .pipe(
            tap(value => {
                this.onChange(typeof value === 'number' ? value : value.counter) <<<< important
                this.onTouched()
            }),
            takeUntil(this.onDestroy$)
        )
        .subscribe()
   }

   }
   writeValue(value: number | { counter: number }) {
    this.myValue = typeof value === 'number' ? value : value.counter
    this.form.setValue({ counter: value > 0 ? value : 0 })
    }
   registerOnChange(fn: () => {}) {
    this.onChange = fn
   }
   registerOnTouched(fn: () => {}) {
    this.onTouched = fn
   }
   setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    // when the parent updates the
    // state of the form control

      if (isDisabled) {
        this.form.disable()
      } else {
        this.form.enable()
      }
   }
   ngOnDestroy(): void {
     this.onDestroy$.next()
     this.onDestroy$.complete()
   }
```